# Tokenizing words from directory of documents returning in wrong order

Tags: python, xml, nltk, tokenize

I am using this code block to parse through a list of 1400 XML files to generate lists of tokenized, stemmed words with stopwords removed from each file:

```
content = []

path = 'assets/cranfield/cranfieldDocs/'
files = os.listdir(path)
stop_list = stopwords.words('english')
st = PorterStemmer()
for file in files:
    tree = ET.parse(os.path.join(path + file))
    root = tree.getroot()
    for idx,log_element in enumerate(root.findall('TEXT')):
        tokens = word_tokenize(log_element.text)
        clean_tokens = [word for word in tokens if word not in stop_list]
        stem_tokens = [st.stem(word) for word in clean_tokens]
        content.append(stem_tokens)
```

However the output I am receiving is not expected. The first doc looks like this:

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO>
1
</DOCNO>
<TITLE>
experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a
wing in a slipstream .
</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>
brenckman,m.
</AUTHOR>
<BIBLIO>
j. ae. scs. 25, 1958, 324.
</BIBLIO>
<TEXT>
  an experimental study of a wing in a propeller slipstream was
made in order to determine the spanwise distribution of the lift
increase due to slipstream at different angles of attack of the wing
and at different free stream to slipstream velocity ratios .  the
results were intended in part as an evaluation basis for different
theoretical treatments of this problem .
  the comparative span loading curves, together with supporting
evidence, showed that a substantial part of the lift increment
produced by the slipstream was due to a /destalling/ or boundary-layer-control
effect .  the integrated remaining lift increment,
after subtracting this destalling lift, was found to agree
well with a potential flow theory .
  an empirical evaluation of the destalling effects was made for
the specific configuration of the experiment .
</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

So the first list of words should be:
`['experiment', 'studi', ..., 'configur', 'experi', '.']`

But instead it is:
`['reciproc', 'equat', ..., 'might', 'conserv', '.']`

Any thoughts as to why it's changing the order of the lists?

Comment: It's just a sort order issue? May be the list contains the right words just in an unexpected order.

Comment: Good point! From a quick ctrl + F I don't think it contains those words though.

Comment: Make sure stop_words does not contain `experiment` for example. Obvious but worth checking.

Comment: Okay got it, will check